# From {{a,b},{c,d}}, {1,2} to {{1,a},{1,b},{2,c},{2,d}} . How?

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine I have these two lists `{{a,b},{c,d}}`, `{1,2}`,  and I want to produce `{{1,a},{1,b},{2,c},{2,d}}`.

The problem is that I have big lists, and doing this element by element is too time consuming. I was wondering if I could 'rewrite' this operation by some other in-built mathematica functions.

I was thinking of something like `MapIndexed[Tuples, {{a, b}, {c, d}}]`, but it doesn't work since Tuples receives `{a,b},{1}` instead of `{{a,b},{1}}`...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Kuba thanks it's a typo. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thread /@ Thread[{{1, 2}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}]
```

But please post a more general example so I could post a better solution, since this might not be enough for your bigger problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works just fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    f[{x_, y_}, z_] := {{z, x}, {z, y}};
    Flatten[MapThread[f, {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {1, 2}}], 1]

  (*   {{1, a}, {1, b}, {2, c}, {2, d}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ;)